# Can I ask "Is this code ok" like questions?

Tags: discussion

For example

Can I post some code and ask whether there is a better way/practice ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to have your working code reviewed, http://codereview.stackexchange.com is the place.

From their [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for **sharing code from projects you are working on**
>   for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a
>   specific working piece of code from your project in the following
>   areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!